# hdiv step by step implementation in strut2

Tags: struts2, hdiv

I need to implement the HDIV concept. I have a page having input fields , which on tampering data is editable. The steps i found are not understandable. 
I am using simple struts2 framework.

Comment: *The latest Struts 2 version supported by HDIV is Struts 2.0.11.* - Which is veeery old.

Comment: What exact problem do you want to solve with hdiv? Probably there are other ways to do so, in less intrusive manner.

Comment: i have a set of input fields on submit, which when i tamper is editable.. basically i dont want it to be editable

Comment: @Gorka The line was taken straight from the hdiv docs. If you're project committer maybe you can fix it.

Comment: You are right Aleksandr, sorry!. Struts 2 support is only offered in HDIV Enterprise Edition. The latest Struts 2 version supported is 2.3.20 and not 2.0.11 as Aleksandr said.